# Atom: error in compilation with gcc for C++

Tags: c++, gcc, atom-editor

I run a very simple program `main.cpp` in c++ that runs from command line without problem:

```
   g++ -o main main.cpp
```

In Atom, I installed the `gpp-compiler 3.0.7` that it doesn't work, not producing the executable and not returning the error

Some suggestions, please?

Comment: I suggest using an IDE if you don't know how you must configure your Editor.

Comment: There's no error message and no executable? Is there anything you could show us that may help us find the problem? Perhaps editor settings or how you set the editor up?

Comment: Perhaps you use some C++ features that the compiler doesn't understand. Show the simple program _and_ the full error output. What does `g++ -dM -E -x c++ - < /dev/null | grep __cplusplus` show?

Comment: Linux?  Macintosh?  Windows?  Did you follow the setup instructions for gpp-compiler?

Comment: Try a verbose switch to see if the compiler even starts.

Comment: The system is Linux

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you install MinGW and add it to your PATH. You need this for the add-on to operate properly. This is for windows. Visit this for mac and linux: https://github.com/kriscross07/atom-gpp-compiler